# Static URL rewrite with htaccess hide full URL path and .html

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, path, url-rewriting

My url is ukneurology.com and the url for one specific program is http://ukneurology.com/html/clinicInfo/stroke.html. I want to change the second URL to ukneurology.com/stroke along with every other page (they will all have a different path). I have seen a lot of dynamic pages, but none of my page URLs look like what I have seen in other examples. I just need an htaccess file where I can type in the real URL and then type in what I want it to look like in the browser and what people can use. Is there a template I can use? Or even better, a generator that will do it for me? I can't find anything!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this: `RewriteRule newPageName oldPageName [L]` Pay attention: you have to escape `.` in the newPageName like this: `\.`. NewPageName and oldPageName don't include your domain.

In your example this would be right: `RewriteRule stroke html/clinicInfo/stroke.html [L]` 
If the user tries to access http://ukneurology.com/stroke, he will see the page http://ukneurology.com/html/clinicInfo/stroke.html without a redirect (so the URL stays the same). The `[L]` avoids that any other RewriteRule will be met.

If you have a special scheme (for example `http://ukneurology.com/abc` => `http://ukneurology.com/html/clinicInfo/abc.html`), you can use a regex to avoid writing thousands of RewriteRules by hand: `RewriteRule ([^/]+) html/clinicInfo/$1.html [L]`